extmark was remove when use `nvim_buf_set_lines`
I am writing a indent (chunk) plugin, and encounter a bug, when comment a line which has extmark, the extmark was remove, detail can be seen here https://github.com/shellRaining/hlchunk.nvim/issues/109
after read the help doc I found that caused by nvim_buf_set_lines, and I found a field called :lockmarks, however I am not sure how to use.
